# Zerocopy TCP message sending from kernel module error EFAULT

Tags: sockets, tcp, linux-kernel, kernel-module

I am working on a kernel module which receives data over DMA from an FPGA and stores it in a ring buffer allocated with `dma_alloc_attrs(dev, size, &data->dma_addr, GFP_KERNEL, DMA_ATTR_FORCE_CONTIGUOUS)`. Everytime when new data is available in the ring buffer, a `completion` is fired.

In the same kernel module, I am running a TCP server and during the lifetime of the kernel module only one client (on a different machine) connects to the server(and stays connected). A separate thread in the kernel module sends data received in the ring buffer to the connected client whenever the `completion` was fired. The idea behind having a tcp server in the kernel space is to get rid of the unnecessary context switches from kernel space and user space whenever the data should be sent to the client, thus increasing performance. So far everything works, but the performance isn't as expected (on the TCP side).

After looking a bit into how to increase performance, i found the `ZEROCOPY` option.

I changed the settings of the server socket to set the `SO_ZEROCOPY` flag: `kernel_setsockopt(socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ZEROCOPY, (char *)&one, sizeof(one))` and the implementation of the sending to client to:

```
static DEFINE_MUTEX(tcp_send_mtx);                                            
static int send(struct socket *sock, const char *buf,         
                const size_t length, unsigned long flags)                
{                                                                             
    struct msghdr msg;                                                        
    struct kvec vec;                                                          
    int len, written = 0;                                                     
    int left = length;                                                        
                                                                              
    if(sock == NULL)                                                          
    {                                                                         
        printk(KERN_ERR MODULE_NAME ": tcp server send socket is NULL\n");    
        return -EFAULT;                                                       
    }                                                                                                                                                 
                                                                              
    msg.msg_name    = 0;                                                      
    msg.msg_namelen = 0;                                                      
    msg.msg_control = NULL;                                                   
    msg.msg_controllen = 0;                                                   
    msg.msg_flags   = MSG_ZEROCOPY;                                       
                                                                              
 repeat_send:                                                                 
    vec.iov_len = left;                                                       
    vec.iov_base = (char *)buf + written;                                     
                                                                              
    len = kernel_sendmsg(sock, &msg, &vec, left, left);                       
                                                                              
    if((len == -ERESTARTSYS) || (!(flags & MSG_DONTWAIT) && (len == -EAGAIN)))
        goto repeat_send;                                                     
                                                                              
    if(len > 0)                                                               
    {                                                                         
        written += len;                                                       
        left -= len;                                                          
        if(left)                                                              
            goto repeat_send;                                                 
    }                                                                         
                                                                                                                                                            
    return written?written:len;                                               
}
```

Note the `msg.msg_flags   = MSG_ZEROCOPY;` assignment in the send function.

Now when i am trying to use this, I am getting `EFAULT(-14)` error code from `kernel_sendmsg` just by adding the `MSG_ZEROCOPY` flag.

UPDATE:

I understand now that the `ZEROCOPY` flag is wrongly used in the kernel space since it's designed to remove the additional copy between the user-space and kernel-space.

My initial problem still exists. TCP transfer is still slow and the ring buffer overflows when the DMA transfer speed exceeds 120mb/s. The thread that forwards the messages to the client is not able to send the 8kb messages faster than 120mb/s.

Anyone knows what is wrong here? Maybe that the idea is wrong in the first place

Comment: It is not clear why you are trying to use a feature that attempts to eliminate copies from user space to kernel space on socket send when the server that sets the socket option is running in kernel space.  Further, it sounds like the client and server are on the same machine (or even in the same kernel module) so the tcp connection is via the loopback.  Maybe reread [this](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/Documentation/networking/msg_zerocopy.rst)?

Comment: @JimD. the client is on a different machine. I thought that ZEROCOPY avoids copying the data to the socket buffers. Is there another way then so increase the performance of the TCP communication? The size of the messages is 8kb

Comment: The feature uses memory shared between kernel and user space to avoid copying data from user space to kernel space, I believe by having non-linear SKBs reference the data in the shared pages if your nic supports scatter gather.  I have no idea if this should work in kernel space.

Comment: You might want to clarify in your question that your "separate thread" that sends the data from the ring buffer to the client is the server which sends the data to the client via the tcp connection.

Comment: Can you add a network capture?  Ideally it would be from a "spanned" port on the switch the server is connected to by a third machine.  Failing that from the server machine.  TCP has a million reasons not to send data, anything could be going on, and this isn't a very large flow.  Assuming the machine is not loaded, nic is 1gb or better, and that the machine has powerful cores (i.e. not a low power embedded device).